# Need help using substring methods in Java

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to print the letter "S". Can anyone point me in the right direction. I don't need the answer, I would like help knowing what I did wrong?

```
    String band = "Rolling Stones";
    int pos = band.indexOf(" ");
    System.out.println(pos);
    System.out.println(band.substring(pos, pos + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument in the `.substring` method is not inclusive. Meaning, you have to end your substring 1 space further than the actual length you want to access. The proper way to do this would be like this:

```
...substring(pos + 1, pos + 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Index of `" "` in your code is `7`. In the next statement, you are printing the index `7` itself  by doing: `substring(7, 8)`.

For `S`, you need to print index `8`. So, the `substring(8, 9)` will give you `S`.

Figure out how to do that with `pos`.